# Move Chrome Browser offscreen to negative y-axis

Tags: google-chrome, raspberry-pi, chromium

I'm trying to hide a portion of a webpage and would like to move the entire window up offscreen.

I can't use an iframe because the page I'm trying to import (outlook.office.com/calendar) has a CSP directive which prevents the page from being imported.

I launch chrome from the command line and when I try to specify a negative y position using `--window-position=x,y`, it just sets y to 0.

Is there some way I can move this to a negative y position?

I'm using Raspi OS but I can use a different OS if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that the Chromium browser window can be moved outside the screen by holding down the `Alt` key, click and dragging the window.

This achieved what I wanted.